# How to communicate from my local machine to web2py?

Tags: python, api, port, web2py, xml-rpc

I need to create a python function that can post a message onto a web2py server from my local machine. In other words, I'd like to see the message I posted with my function at the url of my web2py: http://127.0.0.1:8000/application/controller/view

In accordance to the [Web2Py documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#XMLRPC), I've created the following controller:

```
@service.xmlrpc
def view(message_from_local_machine):
    return message_from_local_machine

def call():
    return service()
```

I've also created view.html as a

```
<h1>{{=message}}</h1>
```

On my local machine I've tried the following

```
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy
server = ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1:8000/application/controller/call/xmlrpc')
server.view('my message from my local machine')
#This returns 'my message from my local machine'
```

Just like the [web2py documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#Remote-procedure-calls) says, I am able to call the function called 'view' remotely. However, the message I used doesnt show up when I visit the following url:
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/application/controller/view'

Instead I get the following message from web2py:

invalid function (controller/view)

I've done research and found [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/web2py/NbO87laofX8), but it says I could use the requests lib or pyserial with Web2Py but does not specify on how to implement. This [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?pli=1#!topic/web2py/Fx_Ov2CZWaA) suggests using qpid.apache.org, but also does not specify how to implement to Web2Py.

Answer (score 1):

First, a function decorated with `@xmlrpc` is meant to be accessed via an XML-RPC client, not via a browser.

Second, if you do want to access a service from the browser, the proper URL format is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/application/controller/call/xmlrpc/view?message_from_local_machine=your_url_encoded_message
```

Of course, the above URL won't work properly because the browser is not an XML-RPC client (the response will be an XML error message).

If you want to call the `view` function from the browser, you can additionally decorate it as an `xml` service:

```
@service.xmlrpc
@service.xml
def view(message_from_local_machine):
    return dict(result=message_from_local_machine)
```

In that case, you would change the URL to specify `xml` rather than `xmlrpc`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/application/controller/call/xml/view?message_from_local_machine=your_url_encoded_message
```

Also, note that above, the return value was changed to a dict -- if you just return a string, you will get malformed XML.

Finally, note that the `view` function is not a web2py action accessible directly via URL. Rather, it is a function registered as a web2py service and therefore only accessible via an action that returns the `service()` object (in this case, the `call` action has been set up to return `service()`, so any functions registered as a service can be accessed via `/default/call/[type_of_service]/[name_of_function]`).

More generally, any function in a controller that takes arguments or starts with a double underscore cannot be accessed directly as an action via URL. Also, when defining service functions, there is no particular reason they must go in a controller -- they can be defined in model files or even in modules. They must simply be decorated with the `@service` decorators.